# Remove the "Today" entry from UIDatePicker

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uidatepicker

When using a UIDatePicker in iOS SDK, there is always an entry "Today" at the current date.
That's useful in most cases, but where I need it, it's rather confusing.

Is there a way to:

a) **disable the "today"-entry** (use regular date instead), and have **all entries look the same**

or even better

b) **disable the "today"-entry** (use regular date instead), and **color the next day in blue**

Further more, the application is for private use only, it's not going to get distributed on the AppStore, which means I *could* use private APIs (I still would rather avoid them) and I don't need it to be backwards compatible. iOS 4 is fine.

Comment: xcode is an IDE, an advanced editor. It has nothing to do with ur code itself.

Comment: Do you need dates prior to "today"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem with the *UIDatePicker* not matching my requirements exactly (in my case I needed a datepicker without a year wheel). Having a look at the [UIDatePicker reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html), it doesn't look like you can disable the today entry, so you might be forced to do what I did.

I used a [UIPickerView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html) and re-implemented the date selection functionality I needed with that.  There are a few things you will need to do to implement your custom date picker:

- Implement a [UIPickerViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIPickerViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) to set up row titles, dimensions and row counts.
- Implement a [UIPickerViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html) to handle events from your custom picker.
- Make sure you update your day wheel when the month wheel changes so you get appropriate days for each month.  UIDatePicker does this pretty seamlessly. With limited time, I just reload the picker when the month changes so the day counts match up.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected to have to do this "manually" by defining the DataSource. It's a little more complicated, but much more flexible. Thank you.