# UIDatePicker doesn't display appropriate time

Tags: iphone, ios, uidatepicker

I have an application that uses UIDatePicker & I am facing problem as described below.

***Problem***
On iOS 5.0, It works perfectly as I need. It is being displayed as follows.

[image: iOS 5.0 Sample DatePicker]

Same Application, behaves differently for iOS 4.3 simulator. Added the screen-shot as follows.

[image]

I am facing this situation while testing on different versions of simulator ( ** iOS 4.3 & iOS 5.0 **). I do have device having iOS 5.0 only. Does anyone have any idea regarding this problem ?

Comment: How are you setting the picker's date?

Comment: Ya i set the pickerdate into .xib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this is a feature of iOS 5. There is a related post where they want the opposite of what you're trying to do, but I believe the same sort of solution should work for you: [Remove the "Today" entry from UIDatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220850/remove-the-today-entry-from-uidatepicker)

Comment: i want to implement this into ios 4.3 my question is how to set the today into ios4.3

Comment: If you follow the solution given at that link you should be able to get what you want, but it is not a trivial task. It involves essentially reimplementing the UIDatePicker. But if getting "Today" is really important to you then that is one way to go.

Answer (score 1):

This might well due to the Time Zone set in the device. Even if you have set same time, but with different timezone, you would get like this.

Comment: It's not a problem of the Timezone