# UIDatepicker date show monday's date only

Tags: iphone, ios, uipickerview, uidatepicker

I want to show only date which is associated with Monday in UIDatePicker, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

With built in UIDatePicker you cannot do that.You will have to create UIPickerview with specific dates you want. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4221063/641062).

Answer (score 0):

for sure, feed your datePicker with an array of the dates that are mondays

just check the nsdate for your desired start date, and the next monday, then work out how much you have to add so is only mondays, create a loop to make your array, and use it as the data source of your picker